# Error in starting pods- kubernetes. Pods remain in ContainerCreating state

Tags: kubernetes

I have installed kubernetes trial version with minikube on my desktop running ubuntu. However there seem to be some issue with bringing up the pods.
Kubectl get pods --all-namespaces shows all the pods in ContainerCreating state and it doesn't shift to Ready.

Even when i do a kubernetes-dahboard, i get

> Waiting, endpoint for service is not ready yet.

Minikube version : v0.20.0

Environment:

- OS (e.g. from /etc/os-release): Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

  VM Driver "DriverName": "virtualbox"

  ISO version "Boot2DockerURL":
  "file:///home/nszig/.minikube/cache/iso/minikube-v0.20.0.iso"

I have installed minikube and kubectl on Ubuntu. However i cannot access the dashboard both through the CLI and through the GUI.

http://127.0.0.1:8001/ui give the below error

```
{ "kind": "Status", "apiVersion": "v1", "metadata": {}, "status": "Failure", "message": "no endpoints available for service "kubernetes-dashboard"", "reason": "ServiceUnavailable", "code": 503 }
```

And minikube dashboard on the CLI does not open the dashboard: Output

```
Waiting, endpoint for service is not ready yet...
Waiting, endpoint for service is not ready yet... 
Waiting, endpoint for service is not ready yet... 
Waiting, endpoint for service is not ready yet...
....... 
Could not find finalized endpoint being pointed to by kubernetes-dashboard: Temporary Error: Endpoint for service is not ready yet 
Temporary Error: Endpoint for service is not ready yet 
Temporary Error: Endpoint for service is not ready yet 
Temporary Error: Endpoint for service is not ready yet
```

kubectl version: `Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7", GitVersion:"v1.7.0", GitCommit:"d3ada0119e776222f11ec7945e6d860061339aad", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-06-29T23:15:59Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"} Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.4", GitCommit:"d6f433224538d4f9ca2f7ae19b252e6fcb66a3ae", GitTreeState:"dirty", BuildDate:"2017-06-22T04:31:09Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`

minikube logs also reports the errors below: 
.....

```
Jul 10 08:46:12 minikube localkube[3237]: I0710 08:46:12.901880 3237 kuberuntime_manager.go:458] Container {Name:php-redis Image:gcr.io/google-samples/gb-frontend:v4 Command:[] Args:[] WorkingDir: Ports:[{Name: HostPort:0 ContainerPort:80 Protocol:TCP HostIP:}] EnvFrom:[] Env:[{Name:GET_HOSTS_FROM Value:dns ValueFrom:nil}] Resources:{Limits:map[] Requests:map[cpu:{i:{value:100 scale:-3} d:{Dec:} s:100m Format:DecimalSI} memory:{i:{value:104857600 scale:0} d:{Dec:} s:100Mi Format:BinarySI}]} VolumeMounts:[{Name:default-token-gqtvf ReadOnly:true MountPath:/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount SubPath:}] LivenessProbe:nil ReadinessProbe:nil Lifecycle:nil TerminationMessagePath:/dev/termination-log TerminationMessagePolicy:File ImagePullPolicy:IfNotPresent SecurityContext:nil Stdin:false StdinOnce:false TTY:false} is dead, but RestartPolicy says that we should restart it. Jul 10 08:46:14 minikube localkube[3237]: E0710 08:46:14.139555 3237 remote_runtime.go:86] RunPodSandbox from runtime service failed: rpc error: code = 2 desc = unable to pull sandbox image "gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0": Error response from daemon: Get https://gcr.io/v1/_ping: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority ....
```

> Name:     kubernetes-dashboard-2039414953-czptd Namespace:    kube-system
>   Node:     minikube/192.168.99.102 Start Time: Fri, 14 Jul 2017 09:31:58
>   +0530 Labels:     k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard        pod-template-hash=2039414953
>   Annotations:  kubernetes.io/created-by={"kind":"SerializedReference","apiVersion":"v1","reference":{"kind":"ReplicaSet","namespace":"kube-system","name":"kubernetes-dashboard-2039414953","uid":"2eb39682-6849-11e7-8...
>   Status:       Pending IP:      Created
>   By:   ReplicaSet/kubernetes-dashboard-2039414953 Controlled
>   By:   ReplicaSet/kubernetes-dashboard-2039414953 Containers:
>   kubernetes-dashboard:
>       Container ID: 
>       Image:        gcr.io/google_containers/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.6.1
>       Image ID:
>       Port:     9090/TCP
>       State:        Waiting
>         Reason:     ContainerCreating
>       Ready:        False
>       Restart Count:    0
>       Liveness:     http-get http://:9090/ delay=30s timeout=30s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
>       Environment:  
>       Mounts:
>         /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kubernetes-dashboard-token-12gdj (ro) Conditions:   Type     Status
>   Initialized   True    Ready   False    PodScheduled   True  Volumes:
>   kubernetes-dashboard-token-12gdj:
>       Type: Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
>       SecretName:   kubernetes-dashboard-token-12gdj
>       Optional: false QoS Class:    BestEffort Node-Selectors:   Tolerations: node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule Events:
>   FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From            SubObjectPath   Type        Reason      Message
>   --------- --------    -----   ----            -------------   --------    ------      -------   1h        11s     443 kubelet, minikube           Warning     FailedSync  Error syncing
>   pod, skipping: failed to "CreatePodSandbox" for
>   "kubernetes-dashboard-2039414953-czptd_kube-system(2eb57d9b-6849-11e7-8a56-080027206461)"
>   with CreatePodSandboxError: "CreatePodSandbox for pod
>   \"kubernetes-dashboard-2039414953-czptd_kube-system(2eb57d9b-6849-11e7-8a56-080027206461)\"
>   failed: rpc error: code = 2 desc = unable to pull sandbox image
>   \"gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0\": Error response from
>   daemon: Get https://gcr.io/v1/_ping: x509: certificate signed by
>   unknown authority"

Comment: That's not enough information to help you. For example, we don't know which driver you're using. My hunch would be you don't have enough resources allocated, for example, try to give it more RAM with `--memory` parameter. Check out https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/minikube for starters.

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas Thanks for the link.. I have edited my question to included more information

Comment: I think you might be hitting https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/311

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas i can't install any package in the vm( LINUX VERSION 4.9.13, gcc version 5.4.0 (Buildroot 2017.02)). Any idea how yo go about it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not super familiar with Minikube, I'm only using Minishift …

Answer (score 2):

It's quite possible that the Pod container images are being downloaded. The images are not very large so the images should get downloaded pretty quickly on a decent internet connection.

You can use `kubectl describe pod --namespace kube-system <pod-name>` to know more details on the pod bring up status. Take a look at the `Events` section of the output.

Until all the kubernetes components in the `kube-system` namespace are in `READY` state, you will not be able to access the dashboard.

You can also try `SSH`'ing into the minikube vm with `minikube ssh` to debug the issue.

Comment: I have edited my post to include details on the pod. Please have a look at it. Thanks

Comment: Any particular debug steps? I am new to kubernetes so specific information would help.

Comment: I would suggest deleting the minikube machine and retrying. Try `minikube stop && rm -rf ~/.minikube && minikube start`

Comment: I am assuming its some error related to certificates which is blocking the container image from being pulled. I can see the error  `CreatePodSandboxError: "CreatePodSandbox for pod \"kubernetes-dashboard-2039414953-czptd_kube-system(2eb57d9b-6849-11e7-8a56-080027206461)\" failed: rpc error: code = 2 desc = unable to pull sandbox image \"gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0\": Error response from daemon: Get https://gcr.io/v1/_ping: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"`

Comment: I faced the same issue with minikube 0.20.0. Upon investigation I noticed that the issue was due to a broken nameserver entry. I logged into the minikube vm using `minikube ssh` and executed the following command `sudo sh -c 'echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf'` to update the DNS server address. At this point everything seemed to be going well, but suddenly my DNS changes got reverted and shit hit the fan all over again. I'm trying to figure out a fix

Comment: Just to follow up on this issue. It seems to have been resolved now. Make sure you remove any existing minikube instance and clear the contents of `~/.minikube` first. In short -> `minikube stop && rm -rf ~/.minikube && minikube start`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to overcome the issue by using a VPN connection for the install and setup. There seems to be some network accessibility issue in my corporate network which is blocking the sandbox image from being pulled.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by doing a clean install using a VPN connection as i had restrictions in my corporate network. This was blocking the site from where the install was trying to pull the sandbox image.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
kubectl config use-context minikube
```

..as a preexisting configuration may have be initiated.

Answer (score 0):

guys i did these and it worked for me

## ON MASTER ONLY

####################

kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=0.0.0.0 --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16

## (copy join)

mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml

ON WORKER NODE ##
###################

kubeadm reset

EXECUTE THE JOIN COMMAND WHICH  YOU GOT FROM MASTER AFTER KUBEADM INIT.
#kubeadm join

Comment: Can you please format your answer using this guide? https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help