# How to install vm with ubuntu image via minikube-kubernetes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubernetes, minikube

I am using minikube to install kubernetes.
This creates a VM with embedded version of linux.
But i want the VM to have a ubuntu operating system. Is there any way to do it?
 Earlier i used the command to install minikube

```
 curl -Lo minikube https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64
```

Comment: You could build your own iso, see: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/contributors/minikube_iso.md

Answer (score 0):

It would be very difficult (and not recommended) to use a different ISO to setup a minikube node. You probably want to setup a single node kubernetes cluster. Take a look at the following resources:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu/local/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu/manual/

Comment: oh i see. The only reason why i wanted to check this is because i have errors in accessing the minikube dashboard. So a link suggested i install openssl in the vm to generate new client key and secret. I couldn't do this with the default image in the vm. Any suggestions on what to do? Basically i want to access the minikube dashboard and i am currently getting the error mentioned in this link https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1682

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004384/error-in-starting-pods-kubernetes-pods-remain-in-containercreating-state?noredirect=1#comment77145569_45004384 I have also posted another question in this link